# Add new location to the Windows 'Save As' form

Tags: robotframework

i need to save report in new directory and then delete it.
Press Key (CRL+S) help me to open 'Save As' window .
Is it possible in Robot Framework to add new path and click Save button?
What keyword can i use to delete existing file?

Comment: You are asking two questions in one. You don't mention what libraries you are using.If it is SeleniumLibrary, then it is not possible. If it is AutoIt or Sikuli, or imagehorizon then you can recongize the field and fill it.

Comment: i am using Press Key from Selenium library and don't know how to change address and then click on Save button in Save As dialog box